# Is there a tool like maqetta for angular js?

Tags: angularjs, maqetta

Maqetta uses dojo(as seen at maqetta.org). 
Is there a tool like that to produce angularjs views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four years later. There are tons of UI widgets for Angular 1, 2, whatever, e.g., [awesome-angular](https://github.com/gianarb/awesome-angularjs). There is an article (almost) about [using Angular components in Maqetta](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2016/08/19/dojo-mixing-dojo-widgets-and-angular-2-components/). But [Maqetta](https://github.com/maqetta/maqetta/) looks rather forgotten. Instead, there are other initiatives that come and go. Still no WYSIWYG for Angular. However, there is the [Polymer Designer Tool](https://polymer-designer.appspot.com/) by Google.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a WYSIWYG editor that uses the core of AngularJS to as it's pedestal. AngularJS doesn't have any pre built UI widgets to reuse like Dojo, so I doubt we will be seeing one anytime soon.